# Module not found :Can't resolve './components/counter' in 'C:/...demo\counter-app\src'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am totally new to React and i'm following tutorials (Programming with MOSH) in youtube but i'm stuck with this error, unable to resolve after finding similar questions.

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import Counter from './components/counter';
//import * as Counter from './components/counter';   //tried this method too

ReactDOM.render(
    <Counter />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

// If you want your app to work offline and load faster, you can change
// unregister() to register() below. Note this comes with some pitfalls.

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

counter.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Counter extends Component {

    render() {
        return <h1> Hello world</h1>;
    }
}

export default Counter;
```

in command prompt i had done `npm install` and `npm start` after deleting package-lock.json but still the same error

folder structure [image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your file structure the `counter.jsx` is a level up, so you'll need `import Counter from '../components/counter';`

Answer (score 1):

Move your components folder inside the SRC this will fix it

Answer (score 0):

Either move components folder inside src folder or change the reference in the import statement to '../component/counter'